# No thickness after export as FBX file

Tags: export, .fbx

I have designed this object in Blender (3.0):
[image]

After exporting it as .fbx file, and opening this .fbx file in an online viewer, or locally in e.g. Ogre mesh viewer it looks like this:

[image]

The thickness of the walls of the box is gone. Do I have to set specific settings when exporting a model from Blender as fbx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thickness is there but you need to "flip your normals". The panels of your box are inside out now.

Comment: Awesome that fixed it, thanks!